# solution for web service call in fragment and place the result in a list view

Tags: json, web-services, android-fragments

how to make a web service call in fragment.
i am working on a project which require a service call and i am working with fragments.
how to make the ***JSON*** call and place the result in a fragment.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your problem properly, you are trying to make webservice call from the fragment. When a fragment creates it calls like below steps:

**onCreate():** The system calls this when creating the fragment. Within your implementation, you should initialize essential components of the fragment that you want to retain when the fragment is paused or stopped, then resumed.

**onCreateView():** The system calls this when it's time for the fragment to draw its user interface for the first time. To draw a UI for your fragment, you must return a View from this method that is the root of your fragment's layout. You can return null if the fragment does not provide a UI.

So better approach will be; in your onCreate() method, call the webservice by using AsyncTask or Volley. If you use AsyncTask, it will call onPostExecute method when its done. Now you create your object (if you follow mvc) and update ui.